# Task.Run code not executing

Tags: .net, task, async-await, c#-5.0

Can someone explain why the SecondTask and the load event not updating the UI given this code?

```
    public Task First()
{
    return Task.Run(
       () =>
        {

            Task.Delay(4000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Title = "From First()";
            });
        });
}
public Task Second()
{
    return Task.Run(
         () =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Title = "From Second()";
            });
            Task.WaitAny(First());
        });

}
    private  void ParentWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Second();
        Title = "From Event";
    }
```

When I run this code, only form's title changes only once as a result of calling First().
Nothing else is executed (at least from what I can see, I can see breakpoints reached).
I have also tried using `Task.WhenAny(First());` instead of `Task.WaitAny(First());`

Comment: Well, did you set some breakpoints, then step through with the debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: Breakpoints are reached, the title never changes passed the call to First()

Comment: You are calling First after Second completes, so you'll see the result from First

Comment: @NedStoyanov, that was the first thing I looked into, so I added 'Task.Delay(5000);'before the call to first and that didn't resolve anything.also, I still have the call in the event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Task.Delay` is not being awaited. `Task.Delay` is an asynchronous sleep so it returns straight away, you need to `await` it if you want to actually continue executing after the delay.

So what happens in the method `Second()` is that the lambda expression gets executed on a background thread. When `Task.Delay(5000)`is called the call returns immediately because it is not awaited, the `Title`is then set to `From Second()`.

```
public Task Second()
{
    return Task.Run(
         () =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000); // need to await here
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Title = "From Second()";
            });
            Task.WaitAny(First());
        });

}
```

`First()` is then called and because the `Task.Delay(4000)`is not awaited either, it immediately sets the `Title`to `From First()`. So the end result is that you will only see `From First()`.

```
public Task First()
{
    return Task.Run(
       () =>
        {

            Task.Delay(4000); // need to await here
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Title = "From First()";
            });
        });
}
```

You also probably want to `await` the call to `Second()` in the event handler unless you intend to first set your title to `From Event` and then override it with the result from `Second()`.

```
    private  void ParentWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Second();  // await this?
        Title = "From Event";
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant to say Task.Delay(4000).Wait(); instead of Task.Delay.Wait(4000);

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to learn about programming with tasks. Please read the articles on [my curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553).

Tasks are executed, you just don't wait them to finish.

The `async-await` makes it easy to do asynchronous work so, you shouldn't mix UI with non-UI code. Try this way:

```
public async Task FirstAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    Title = "From First()";
}

public async Task SecondAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Title = "From Second()";
    await FirstAsync();
}

private async void ParentWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await SecondAsync();
    Title = "From Event";
}
```

This will do what you want and it's much cleaner code.